# Rigged model arm deforming body

Tags: modeling, rigging, pose-mode

So I've been reading about riggin in blender, just started doing it, and I wanted to rig a simple model.
The problem is that when I move the arms down, the body deforms pretty badlt, and the model doesn't look round and fat anymore :(
Got any tips for a begginer to fix this problem?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your pics, you have already explored Weight Paint mode. That's going to be the key. The body is collapsing because of how the automatic weights were calculated. If you look at all that light blue on the torso in your third pic, where the arm's vertex group is active, you can see that there is entirely too much arm bone influence on the main body. Just paint it out so that it is darker blue. Set your weight brush to *Draw*, and set your **Weight** setting all the way down, and your **Strength** setting all the way up, and go over the torso.

You may have to tweak the edges of these zones of influence at some point. Use the *Blur* or *Average* brush for that.

Comment: Well, I thought that too, so I started painting the weights, but I encountered another problem, I made the model facing the X axis, so all the symmetry tools give me problems cuz they seem to work using the X axis as mirror. Got any solution to that? Using the apply delta transform doesn't help.

Comment: Edit: Well, never mind, I fixed it by messing around with the apply tools. I'll update you when I fix the weights.

Comment: It seems that the model needs more bones or I need to start a rigging course if I want to make it look nice :s. https://imgur.com/kYkSwK5

Comment: Yeah, rigging is hard. One thing you might consider trying, though, is experimenting with Rigify. Granted, the shape of your character is a little different than what the Rigify metarig generally expects. But I'm thinking you can probably tweak the bones enough before generating the final rig to make it work for you.